# Ignore certain exit codes in GitLab CI pipeline script

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I have a script in GitLab CI but one command sometimes ends with exit code 101 what is OK in my use case and I want to ignore it.

I would use true:

```
failing_script || true
```

But it will ignore all exit codes, so I will not be notified when there will be some other error.

I would need something like this:

```
failing_script || (true only if exit code 101)
```

Comment: Do you need to exit with the original status if it is neither 0 nor 101?  If so, then you have to work a bit harder than if it is sufficient to exit with a non-zero exit code (e.g. `1`) when anything goes wrong.

Comment: Not necessary, @Frumpled answer is good enough and elegant. But it could be useful for others to know how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```sh
failing_script|| [ $? -eq 101 ]
```